# Redefine function arguments before rendering

Tags: functions, filters

How to change args values before function output (filter default values before call)

```
wp_function($arg1,$arg2 = false){code}
```

change to

```
wp_function($arg1,$arg2 = true){code}
```

without [php runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Change the argument defaults of a function?

Comment: Yes! filter default values of a function

Answer (score 2):

*Redefining a WordPress core function* that might be used all over the place by the core, the theme or plugins *isn't a very good idea* in my opinion. Because it might be used in those occasions expecting the default value to be what default is, which might lead to breaking things. So it is actually not just not a very good idea, *it is a terrible one* - in my honest opinion.

Besides I don't quite get why you can't just call/invoke the function, in the cases you need the second argument to be not the default, with the second argument declared to be what you need to get the output you want, like this:

```
wp_function( $arg1, true );
```